# ggplot, geomline not looking right

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot my data using ggplot and `geomline` in R studio but somehow the plot is not looking right. This is my sample data:
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpAf1.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = data_south, mapping = aes(x = Month, y = Tempture), color="blue")
```

This is the output I am getting:
[image: Plot Result]

But this plot is not looking right. The lines are supposed to be connected and also why there are straight lines in the plot?

Comment: You have multiple values at each independent variable, thus the vertical lines.  What were you expecting?  Maybe a box plot is a better graph for this situation.

Comment: You might try this instead of `geom_line`:  `stat_summary(aes(x = Month, y = Tempture), fun = mean, geom = "line")` -- that should make a line connecting the average of each of the monthly values.

Comment: Or you might add the days back in implicitly, perhaps `library(dplyr); data_south %>% group_by(Month) %>% mutate(Month_dec = Month + row_number() / n()) %>% ungroup() %>% ggplot(aes(Month_dec, Tempture)) + geom_line()`

Comment: Or just use `geom_point()` and `geom_smooth()`

Comment: Please use dput() and paste a sample of your data instead of posting a screenshot.